# what is the expectation of identity matrix

Tags: calculus, statistics, optimization, expected-value

I would like to get an upper bound for this term
$$ E\left[\left( \|I\| +b\right)^2 \left\|c^2\|x-x_1\|\right\|^2\right]$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix  and b and c are constants. Am I allowed to write
$$ E\left[\left( \|I\| +b\right)^2 \left\|c^2\|x-x_1\|\right\|^2\right]\leq E\left[\left( \|I\| +b\right)^2 \right] 
c^2E\left[\left\|\|x-x_1\|\right\|^2\right]?$$
If yes, then what is $E[\|I\|]$?

Comment: The identity matrix is deterministic, so $E (\|I\|)=\|I\|$ You should pull out all the constants outside the expectation.

Comment: Thanks, @Jose, then am I allowed to write them as the product rules?

Comment: $$ c^2\left( \|I\| +b\right)^2E\left[ \left\|\|x-x_1\|\right\|^2\right]$$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.